# Overload method with different HashMap parameters

Tags: java, function, hashmap, overloading

I'm making this method with multiple parameters: `createExportJob (String testId, Long otherId )` to reduce duplicate code. this example of the method should be the minimum amount of parameters the method should use.

```
private void createExportJob (String testId, Long otherId )  {
        String testname = getTestName(testId);

        Configuration config = itsExportService.getConfiguration();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("EXAMPLE", config.getExample();
        params.put("EXAMPLENAME", config.getExampleName();
        params.put("TESTNAME", testName);
        ExportJob queuedJob = ExportQueue.addJob(params, testId, otherId);

    }
```

In some cases i want to include more `params.put` to the `HashMap` in the method, like this:

```
  params.put("THEYESNO", theYesNo ? "YES" : "NO");
```

**Or**

```
  params.put("COORDINATES", String.valueOf(minX)+","+String.valueOf(minY)+"
        ',"+String.valueOf(maxX)+","+String.valueOf(maxY));
```

How do I **overload** this method with more input parameters?
Or is there any **better** solution to solve this case than overloading?

Comment: why don't you create one function with all parameters and check for nulls

Comment: do those values only apply if they are sent as params? How do you expect to return values from methods with returntype void?

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya probably, because than in all method calls you would need to pass those nulls

Comment: Sorry it should be no return in this method should just do the export job. Yes the values need to be sent as params.

Comment: You only need two versions, one is the original version with string and long and one contains an additional Map parameter with _additional_ parameters which you then add to `params` let the caller decide which additional params it needs

Comment: Where do the `min`/`max` and `yesNo` values come from, also the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Builder`.

```
class ExportJobConfigBuilder {
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
 public Map<String, String> build() {
  return params;
 }
 // fill basic data in constructor
 public ExportJobConfigBuilder (String name, Configuration config) {
  params.put("TESTNAME", name);
  params.put("EXAMPLE", config.getExample();
  params.put("EXAMPLENAME", config.getExampleName();
  return this;
 }
 public ExportJobConfigBuilder withCoords(int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY) {
  params.put("COORDINATES", String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d", minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
  return this;
 }
 public ExportJobConfigBuilder withYesNo(boolean yesNo) {
  params.put("THEYESNO", theYesNo ? "YES" : "NO");
  return this;
 }
}
```

Now you have ultimate flexibility in choosing what information you add without adding separate methods for each combination. You'd call it with

```
ExportJobConfigBuilder builder = 
  new ExportJobConfigBuilder(getTestname(testId), itsExportService.getConfiguration());
builder.withCoords(minx, miny, maxx, maxy); // or not
builder.withYesNo(yesNo); // or not
Map<String, String> params = builder.build();

ExportJob job = ExportQueue.addJob(params, testId, otherId);
```

If you need to add additional parameters on the way, you will only need to add one method to the builder, and you can leave existing code untouched.

Comment: That was exactly [what I was thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66459052/507738) :-)

Comment: @MCEmperor Ouch... sorry for ninja'ing you :D

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
private void createExportJob (String testId, Long otherId, Boolean theYesNo, Long minX, Long minY, Long maxX, Long maxY) {
            String testname = getTestName(testId);
    
            Configuration config = itsExportService.getConfiguration();
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("EXAMPLE", config.getExample();
            params.put("EXAMPLENAME", config.getExampleName();
            params.put("TESTNAME", testName);
            
            if(theYesNo != null)
                params.put("THEYESNO", theYesNo ? "YES" : "NO"); 
                
            if(minX != null) {// you can check other params also
                params.put("COORDINATES", String.valueOf(minX)+","+String.valueOf(minY)+
                            "',"+String.valueOf(maxX)+","+String.valueOf(maxY));
            }
            
            ExportJob queuedJob = ExportQueue.addJob(params, testId, otherId);
    
    }
        
    private void createExportJob (String testId, Long otherId){
        createExportJob(testId, otherId, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    
    private void createExportJob (String testId, Long otherId, Boolean theYesNo){
        createExportJob(testId, otherId, theYesNo, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

If there are too many parameters you can use another map containing all the additional parameters and do the null check on that.